# Add element to array member of a struct

Tags: c

I have an union:

`typedef union { int arr1[5]; char arr2[5]; } type`

and a struct:

`typedef struct { int size; type elt; } foo`

and finally a variable:

`foo bar = { 3, {1,2,3} }`.

I want to add an element to bar. Therefore I defined:

```
void myfun(foo x, int new) 
{
      x.elt.arr1[x.size] = new;
      x.size += 1;
      return;
}
```

If I call `myfun(bar,4)` it should change bar appropriately. But if I view the elements of `bar` before and after the call of `myfun` it will print `bar` without the additional element.

Edit: My view function is:

```
void myprint(foo x)
{
     for ( int i = 0; i < x.size; i++) {
           printf("%d ", x.elt.arr1[i]);
      }
      return;
}
```

What's my fault?

Comment: How do you "view the elements of `bar`"?  Can you provide a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: Function arguments are passed by value, so you aren't modifying the original structure but a copy.

Comment: change your call by reference (&) and modifiy a bit your function to use a pointer , and it should be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As interjay wrote, you are not modifying bar, but just a coppy (that is created separately in memory everytime when function myfun is called). Look up difference between functions called by value and functions called by reference. What you need is:

```
void myfun(foo *x, int new) 
{
    x->elt.arr1[x->size] = new;
    x->size += 1;
    return;
}
```

and then:

```
myfun(&bar,4)
```

That way, variable bar will be edited.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Edit that post if you find something wrong, I can't check it on this PC and I am horrible with syntax :D.